# Writing content into txt file python

Tags: python

Here I am writing some content to text file in python,when I try running this without writing a function, it runs well and I get the desired result but when I try applying a def function(): the same doesn't happen.Any help would be useful to learn.

```
def fu(self):
    self.xmldoc = minidom.parse('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Doc\\abc.xml')
    self.tree = ET.parse('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Doc\\abc.xml')
    self.root = self.tree.getroot()
    self.validate_model = self.xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('MODEL')
    self.extract_model = self.validate_model[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    # print("hi "+extract_model[len(extract_model)-1:])
    self.headerlist = self.xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('HW_VERSION')
    self.validate_header = self.headerlist[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    # print("HW_VERSION: " + validate_header)
    # print("Length of HW_VERSION: " + str(len(validate_header)))
    if re.match('^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.]*$', self.validate_header):
        print("The HW_VERSION is valid")
    else:
        print("Sorry")
        self.save_path = "C:\\Users\\c\\Downloads\\errors"
        self.name_of_file = "Error_log1"
        self.completeName = os.path.join(self.save_path, 
        self.name_of_file + ".txt")
        file1 = open(self.completeName, 'rw')
        file1.write("Error Log file created at " + "\n")
        file1.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + "\n")
        file1.write("-------------------------------------" + "\n")
    file1.close()
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Your `else` is bad indented. Is that a StackOverflow post problem or is that wrong in your original file?

Comment: Its a stack overflow post problem

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your given code is syntactically illegal, and there is no driver program to make the function work.

Comment: did you even call the function after defining it ?

Comment: I just called it like print(fu()), , correct me if i am wrong in it please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have self as a parameter, that means you are in a python class, since you didn't actually pass in a value for self when you called fu. You should either declare a class object and call the fu method from that, or pass in a value for the self parameter (most likely your file/directory/path).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a couple things to check:

1. Your indentation. Your `else` statement (and all code below) isn't indented properly with respect to everything else.
2. How you called different variables, etc, from packages. Since you didn't post all  of your code, I don't know for sure, but you might need to do `from xml import etree` (among other things) and then do `etree.ElementTree` instead of `ET`.
3. Did you actually call the function with the appropriate argument? After adding in all the necessary import statements and fixing the indentation, I got no errors. For reference, here's the code I ended up using:

   ```
   import os
   import re
   import datetime
   from xml import dom 
   from xml import etree

   def fu(self):
       self.xmldoc = dom.minidom.parse('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Doc\\abc.xml')
       self.tree = etree.ElementTree.parse('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Doc\\abc.xml')
       self.root = self.tree.getroot()
       self.validate_model = self.xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('MODEL')
       self.extract_model = self.validate_model[0].firstChild.nodeValue
       # print("hi "+extract_model[len(extract_model)-1:])
       self.headerlist = self.xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('HW_VERSION')
       self.validate_header = self.headerlist[0].firstChild.nodeValue
       # print("HW_VERSION: " + validate_header)
       # print("Length of HW_VERSION: " + str(len(validate_header)))
       if re.match('^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.]*$', self.validate_header):
           print("The HW_VERSION is valid")
       else:
           print("Sorry")
       self.save_path = "C:\\Users\\c\\Downloads\\errors"
       self.name_of_file = "Error_log1"
       self.completeName = os.path.join(self.save_path, self.name_of_file + ".txt")
       file1 = open(self.completeName, 'w')
       file1.write("Error Log file created at " + "\n")
       file1.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + "\n")
       file1.write("-------------------------------------" + "\n")
       file1.close()
   ```

If as you say in your comment you ran this as `print(fu())` then there's another problem. Your function needs an argument! If your function `fu()` was in an object, then that would have worked; instead, you need to provide an argument, probably (as @CaryShindell's answer says) your file name/path.